# Border Control in Windows Phone 7, Auto Height & Width not right

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a `ListBox` with this template in it.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,10">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFC000" Width="460" MinHeight="76">
                <StackPanel Margin="4,4,-4,-153">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock " Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Yet I have to force set a `Width` and `Height` on the `Border` otherwise it makes like `Width` and `Height` of "2".

It is like it does not understand I have 2 `TextBlock` inside it and won't expand to fill both of them.

This leaves me with having to put a fixed height and width in what I don't like as if the text is too big it gets cutoff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toss out your `StackPanel`'s because you don't need them, they're also what's keeping your wrapping from working, you need a panel like a `Grid` for that. The negative `Margin`'s also isn't something you'd normally see in a `DataTemplate` for a `ListBox` so I'd guess you have some other funky layout stuff going on from that sort of practice elsewhere up the tree.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
         <Grid Margin="0,10">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFC000"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,4,-4,-153"> 
                 <Run Text="{Binding }"/><LineBreak/>
                 <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

So unless I'm missing something somewhere this should fix you up as the `Grid` will handle the sizes of its children for you and consume the space necessary in its parent. However if there's something else in your structure pushing stuff around and won't let it consume that space it should invoke your Wrapping.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well I was just playing around might have accidentally hit something with -4 to happen, I removed that and changed to grid. how about in the item template, I had a stack panel there as well can that stay or change? It actually seems to be the outer stack panel that caused the trouble inner one seems fine.

Comment: I don't have LineBreak do I need to import something?

Comment: Ya the inner one controlling the two TextBlocks wouldn't be the culprit, I just go all OCD on some xaml sometimes. As for the LineBreak, I didn't bother testing it on WP7 I just figured that was something that was pretty much universal to XAML so you may need to go back to your old way with the separate TextBlocks and using it, it's the Grid as container that is your main champ on this one :)